# read text file and save the content in an array using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I've searched a lot about this topic, but couldn't find solution. I have a *.txt file containing coordinates (each line has one coordinate) in one column. So, I want to read this file from my file system and use those coordinates to visualize the tracking route on Google Maps API v3. I've already visualized the track for three coordinates and it works fine. 
Can anybody just share a sample code of reading a *.txt file and fill an array with the file content? Maybe this is quite easy thing, but I am really stuck on this and would appreciate your help!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications

Answer (score 0):

You can't read a file using javascript. It's a client-side programming language. But some developpers have developped a solution.

Check this link and tell me if it was helpful for you: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/read-text-files-using-the-javascript-filereader.html#fbid=iTAoMveIKhq

Comment: Is it possible to pass the array from jsp to javascript?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to share a sample code but you could read the answers to that similar question :

[Javascript - read local text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446447/javascript-read-local-text-file)

Basically loading the txt file with Ajax, and read the `responseText`attribute of the response.

Although it would be easier to read a xml file or a json file, which would be easier to parse than a simple txt file.